# Setting {{ user.email }} as input value does not save Django form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to set the default value of an input as `{{ user.email }}` so that the user does not have to type their email again when they are submitting a POST request. When a user signs up for an account, they use their email and I store it in a model. However, when I was testing this, I get a field error saying that the email field is required.

I am printing the error in my `views.py` file like this:

```py
form = UserDataForm(request.POST)
for field in form:
    print("field_error: ", field.name, field.errors)
```

```html
field_error: email <ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>
```

I am setting the input value through JavaScript like so, and I am also hiding the input by setting the `display` to `none`:

```js
document.querySelector("#id_email").setAttribute("value", "{{user.email}}")
document.querySelector("#id_email").value = "{{user.email}}"
document.querySelector("#id_email").style.display = "none"
```

I used inspect element and i see that the input tag shows the email in the value attribute:

```html
<input type="email" name="email" maxlength="320" required id="id_email" value="test@gmail.com" style="display: none;">
```

`forms.py`:

```py
class UserDataForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label="Email address")
    # other fields
```

`models.py`:

```py
class UserDataModel(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(default="", max_length=100)
    # other fields
```

`views.py`:

```py
from .models import UserDataModel
from .forms import UserDataForm

def profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = UserDataForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            f = UserDataModel(
                email = cd['email'],
                # other fields
            )
            f.save()
    else:
        form = UserDataForm()

    return render(request, 'profile.html', {"form": form})
```

`profile.html`:

```html
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="/profile/" method="post" id="questions" class="hide">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
</form>
<script>
    document.querySelector("#id_email").setAttribute("value", "{{user.email}}")
    document.querySelector("#id_email").value = "{{user.email}}"
    document.querySelector("#id_email").style.display = "none"
</script>
{% endif %}
```

If I am doing something wrong, please tell me as I am kind of new to Django. I would really appreciate the help because I have been working on this for hours, huge thanks.

I was expecting for the form to save.

Answer (score 0):

The html template is trying to use `{{user.email}}` as the value of the input element:

```
document.querySelector("#id_email").value = "{{user.email}}"
```

But the view function does not provide a variable named `user`, it only provides a variable named `form`:

```
return render(request, 'profile.html', {"form": form})
```

...so the html template treats `{{user.email}}` as a blank string.

Perhaps you meant to use `{{form.email}}` instead?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to include that I am using Google OAuth to sign users in. So in my html file, I used this Django template tag:
```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %} 
    <!-- render html here -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error you're describing is only in the `for loop`

```
for field in form:
    print("field_error: ", field.name, field.errors)
```

Then that's not an error. What you're doing there is just accessing the errors of the fields. When you create a Django form, it will add such kind of errors so it shows them when necessary.

As your code is, it should work fine. If you can check, I bet you can see it's saving your data to the database.